# Query Optimization Recommendations

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to optimize a script that runs out of spool space and times out. The purpose of the query is to return three columns: Case_ID, CxC1_ECN, and CxC2_ECN. The end result displays a table that shows different ECN's that share the same Case_ID for comparison.

The script runs a table against itself. I am using TD Sql Assistant.

Any insight on how to improve this script in order to make it more efficient is greatly appreciated.

```
Select Distinct CTT_Case.Case_ID, 
    CxC1.ECN as CxC1_ECN,
    CxC2.ECN as CxC2_ECN
From BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case
    Join BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case_x_Cust CxC1 On CxC1.Case_ID = CTT_Case.Case_ID
    Join BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case_x_Cust CxC2 On CxC2.Case_ID = CxC1.Case_ID And CxC2.ECN<> CxC1.ECN;
```

Comment: Post the explain plan.

Comment: 1) First, we lock BMGU_CDM.CxC1 for read on a reserved RowHash to
     prevent global deadlock.
  2) Next, we lock BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case for read on a reserved RowHash to
     prevent global deadlock.
  3) We lock BMGU_CDM.CxC1 for read, and we lock BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case for
     read.

Comment: 4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from BMGU_CDM.CxC1 by way of an
     all-rows scan with a condition of ("NOT (BMGU_CDM.CxC1.Case_ID IS
     NULL)") into Spool 3 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the
     hash code of (BMGU_CDM.CxC1.Case_ID) to all AMPs.  The size of
     Spool 3 is estimated with low confidence to be 29,753,568 rows (
     743,839,200 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.18
     seconds.

Comment: 5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case by way of an
     all-rows scan with a condition of (  "(BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case.Population_Type <= 2) AND
     (BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case.Population_Type >= 1)"), which is joined to
     Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan.

Comment: BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case
     and Spool 3 are joined using a single partition hash join, with a
     join condition of ("Case_ID = BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case.Case_ID").  The
     result goes into Spool 4 (all_amps), which is built locally on the
     AMPs.  Spool 4 is built as in-memory optimized spool with 4 column
     partitions.  The size of Spool 4 is estimated with no confidence
     to be 5,950,715 rows (220,176,455 bytes).

Comment: 6) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from BMGU_CDM.CxC2 by way of an
     all-rows scan with a condition of ("NOT (BMGU_CDM.CxC2.Case_ID IS
     NULL)") into Spool 5 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the
     hash code of (BMGU_CDM.CxC2.Case_ID) to all AMPs.  Spool 5 is
     built as in-memory optimized spool with 4 column partitions.  The
     size of Spool 5 is estimated with low confidence to be 29,753,568
     rows (981,867,744 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
     0.18 seconds.

Comment: 7) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 4 (Last Use), which is
     joined to Spool 5 (Last Use).  Spool 4 and Spool 5 are joined
     using a single partition in-memory hash join, with a join
     condition of ("(Case_ID = Case_ID) AND ((Case_ID = Case_ID) AND
     (ECN <> ECN ))").  The result goes into Spool 2 (all_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated
     with no confidence to be 44,216,274 rows (1,547,569,590 bytes).
     The estimated time for this step is 0.10 seconds.

Comment: 8) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 2 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan, grouping by field1 (
     BMGU_CDM.CTT_Case.Case_ID ,BMGU_CDM.CxC1.ECN ,BMGU_CDM.CxC2.ECN).
     Aggregate Intermediate Results are computed locally, then placed
     in Spool 1.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence
     to be 33,162,206 rows (2,022,894,566 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.19 seconds.

Comment: 9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.70 seconds.